# Customise core-dump filename and path?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, coredump, crash-dumps

I have an application which generates core-dump files by default. This is enabled by calling

```
struct rlimit core_limits;

core_limits.rlim_cur=core_limits.rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY;
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &core_limits);
```

at the very beginning of this application.

Now is there also a possibility to modify the name and location of the file generated? So what I want to have instead of "core.[pid]" is something like "myapp_core.dmp" and to force it to always store it e.g. in the home directory of the current user?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. See **core(5)** (`man 5 core`) for details on setting the naming pattern.

Comment: However, I don't know how to make the core dump go to the current user's home directory.